# Multi-target regression using scikit-learn without ytrain

Tags: python, regression, multi-label-classification

I would like to use the multi-target regression with scikit-learn. However, the examples I've seen use Xtrain and ytrain?

What is ytrain in regression?

I know y it is used for classes in classification. My data is composed of two columns of data, and I want to predict both values independently (but using a single MTR). So, I have clear X is a training set of n number of samples from those two values, however, I don't know how to create y.

My data is composed of two attributes not correlated, I guess this is Xtrain. What should I use as ytrain?

I'm based on this source https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-output-regression-models-with-python/.

Any clue?

Comment: It's not fully clear what you're asking here. Is your question "What are the labels supposed to be in a multi-target regression problem?", or are you asking what are the labels supposed to be in **any** regression problem and not just "multi-target regression problem"? Could you also explain what you mean by "multi-target" here? Moreover, the article that you mention does not contain the words `Xtrain` or `ytrain`, after a quick search.

Comment: Right, doesn't say Xtrain or ytrain, but X and y. In my case, X, is composed for two non-correlated variables (latitude and longitude) as input, I want the same as output (latitude and longitude but predicted. So, I have N number of samples and I want to predict M number of samples (in both cases composed for the same number of variables). There are not more input neither labels. I don't know if it is clear.